# Is dynamic scala generics possible?

Tags: scala, generics

I have a method which returns an Object type wrapped object that originally was either a String, Int, Long, Boolean, etc

I also have an overloaded set of methods which are tailored for each individual class but not the Object type

My goal is to build a generic implementation that will inspect the object typed as Object and will explicitly cast it to the appropriate underlying class inspecting a given set of class types in a particularly predetermined order. The first matching class would warrant a method call with the object cast as the particular underlying class.

Here is a copy/paste based code example of what I am trying to achieve but would like it expressed in a loop or some other device, where the types are inspected from a List or some other collection device such that this list could be defined once, and used in many cases matching the pattern:

```
val o : Object = "string"
if (o.isInstanceOf[String] ) f(o.asInstanceOf[String] ) else
if (o.isInstanceOf[Boolean]) f(o.asInstanceOf[Boolean]) else
if (o.isInstanceOf[Int]    ) f(o.asInstanceOf[Int]    ) else
if (o.isInstanceOf[Double] ) f(o.asInstanceOf[Double] )
```

What I would like (and note, the following is obviously not scala, but... perhaps there is a way how to express a similar pattern in scala)

```
val o : Object = "string"
val t = List(String,Boolean,Int,Double)
for (T <- t) if(o.isInstanceOf[T]) f(o.asInstanceOf[T])
```

Any help would be very much appreciated

Here is a more concrete example:

```
val n : org.neo4j.graphdb.Node = ...
var j : com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode = ...
val p = "someProperty"
val o = n.getProperty(p) // returns Object (do not confuse w ObjectNode)
if (o.isInstanceOf[String ]) j.put(p,o.asInstanceOf[String ]) else
if (o.isInstanceOf[Boolean]) j.put(p,o.asInstanceOf[Boolean]) else
if (o.isInstanceOf[Int]    ) j.put(p,o.asInstanceOf[Int]    ) else
...
```

Comment: You're probably looking for `typeclasses`. Can you provide more details about what kind of operations you want to do with the different objects?

Comment: I brushed up on `typeclasses` a bit by reading the following http://www.smartjava.org/content/scala-typeclass-explained-implement-stringread-function. And I still do not see how I could leverage to achieve the desired goal without having to do a boat load of coding for each different f(). Note, in my case f() is a method from some black box class in a jar, and there are many different kinds of f() w different signatures, but they all function in a similar pattern. And all I want to do is to call any f() like method with the object cast to appropriate type (wo writing a wrapper for each f())

Comment: I think I understand what you are trying to achieve, but it would really help if you can specify the ultimate intent, the "why". What are the operations you want to perform after those values are "casted"? Knowing this, I can probably suggest a better answer.

Comment: I am using APIs that I treat as black boxes, one API returns a variable of the type Object (although that object was really originally within the API created as either String, Boolean, Int, etc), I have another set of black box APIs that take in String or Boolean or Int, but not Object, and autocasting does not function (both APIs are Java), and I am looking for a concise way of calling the second API with the returned value from the first one. In a nut shell calling `api2(api1())` and casting types because I have to. Cannot mod either api, writing full wrappers is too much work too.

Comment: The things you mention (cannot modify either api, can't do full wrappers, etc) definitely hint towards typeclasses. But still you haven't given a concrete example (what methods are you wanting to call), which is needed to show how a typeclass solution would work.

Comment: I added the more concrete example in the question itself

Comment: Given that you're trying to use the right overload of the `put` function, but you're starting with `Object` you're not going to do much better than @AndreiT's answer. Somehow, you have to provide a mapping from a type to the right overload of "put", so you'll have both the type and the function (the overloaded put) repeated for each type. You're trying to have the compiler make a decision at compile-time, with information that is only available at runtime. Of course, you can hide match statement behind some helper function...

Comment: I view either of the two solutions (mine and Adrei T's equally inelegant, in that they are overly verbose and non reusable). I am hoping someone will come up with a more elegant solution. In terms of the compiler knowing at compile time vs runtime, I am sure there can be devices created such as say declarative constants (things that can be declared once and cannot be modified) such that compiler could permit more dynamic processing of types at runtime yet have full capacity to perform compile time validation (as the data parts of that limited dynamic processing would be static)

Comment: Introduction of generics was a step in that direction, although, I believe there are more steps that can be taken. At any rate, it would seem that according to the present specs and implementation of Scala what I want is unachievable. At any rate, thank you guys for the inputs, and I am always very much open for alternative points of view.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly, I think what you are looking for is pattern matching:

```scala
val object: Any = "string"
object match {
  case o: String  => // do some string operation on `o`
  case o: Boolean => // do some boolean operation on `o`
  case o: Int     => ...
  case o: Double  => ...
}
```

Of course pattern matching can be used in much granular way. Hope that helps :)

Comment: No, not really, or at least I cannot figure out how to leverage pattern matching such that I would not have to repeat the function call f() as many times as the types I have. I will try to clarify this in the original question.

Comment: I see. Now that you mentioned it, you should use typeclasses, as @Alvaro Carrasco advised. Please add more details about the operation though so that we can imagine how a typeclass will look :) See an example here - http://eed3si9n.com/herding-cats/Eq.html